# Reuse popout window

Tags: javascript, window

I am trying to reuse a popout window but I just keep getting a NEW window opening every time.

```
 var windowObjectReference,
        url,
        strWindowName,
        strWindowFeatures;

windowObjectReference = window.open(url, strWindowName, strWindowFeatures);
```

What am I doing wrong? I have the "name" the same everytime.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of the question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638910/javascript-check-for-duplicate-opened-window

Answer (score 0):

It could be an influence of a pop-up blocker. Make sure you disable pop-up blocking in your browser and try again. Furthermore, keep in mind that the window name must not contain blank spaces.

From the [MDN documentation on window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open):

> `var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);`
>
> If a window with the name strWindowName already exists, then strUrl is loaded into the existing window.

... but this is not the case when the browser blocks your pop up. In that case, at least for Chrome and IE9, a new window is always created.